# Reconciling inconsistent floating precision from query in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, floating-point

When I run a query like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(
  "select score, coalesce(null, score), score * 1.0"\
  " from table limit 1"
)
enter code here
```

I get back a result like:

```
[[805.92, 805.9199829101562, 805.9199829101562]]
```

From [this discussion](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42666) it looks like the discrepancy is due to mysql converting float fields to doubles before performing any arithmetic.

Is there any way to reliably make these two values the same once they are in ruby? Is there a method to covert the last two values back to single per precision, or the first value to double precision?

edit:

I found running

```
[805.92].pack('f').unpack('f')
```

yields:

```
[805.9199829101562]
```

Though I haven't confirmed that this will always work.

Comment: Use BigDecimal which has fixed-place arithmetic or be prepared for the wild, weird world of [floating point math](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Your database probably has a `coerce` function that will convert results to whatever you like...

Comment: @tadman `BigDecimal` could solve the opposite issue, but here it’s MySQL who corrupts data due to floating point operation and I am not sure how `BigDecimal` would help.

Comment: Why not declare the columns as decimal or double instead of fp?

Comment: @max That isn't something I have control over.